# What is the intuition behind equations 10, 11 and 12 of the paper "Noise2Noise: Learning Image Restoration without Clean Data"?

Tags: deep-learning, objective-functions, papers, activation-functions

Can anyone help me understand these functions described in the paper [Noise2Noise: Learning Image Restoration without Clean Data](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.04189)

I have read the portion A.4 in the appendix but need a more detailed and easier to understand explanation. Especially where signum or sign function (sgn) is coming from along with other explanations.

(10),(11),(12)

[image]